# How to import the setState function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

The file Editor.js in the components directory contains this

```
const Editor = () => {
  //some states
  const [mathEditorVisible, setMathEditorVisible] = useState(false);
  //some other code
}
```

This is Form.js in the utils directory:

```
//some imports
export const handleSaveFormula = (latex) => {
  //some code
  setMathEditorVisible(false);   
};
```

This is Editor.js in the utils directory:

```
//some exports
export const editExpression = () => {
  //some code
  setMathEditorVisible(true);
};
```

Now, I want to import the setMathEditorVisible from Editor.js in the components directory where it is defined to the Editor.js and Form.js files in the utils directory.
This error occurs if I do not import it

```
src/utils/Editor.js
  Line 17:8:  'setMathEditorVisible' is not defined  no-undef

src/utils/Form.js
  Line 49:7:  'setMathEditorVisible' is not defined  no-undef
```

And of course it will because it is undefined for now.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What is the reason it has to work like this? More specifically, why do `handleSaveFormula` and `editExpression` need to modify the state of a different component?

Comment: You can't do such thing actually, importing a state setter in react is either possible with props, or with context.

I suggest if the components tree is complicated in your project use React Context Hooks, otherwise, just use the props to share data between parents and children.

However, you can use Redux Toolkit for complex State Management, it helps a lot and saves you time.

Comment: Actually, I have to set the visibility of the MathEditor component at the end of those two functions: editExpression and handleSaveFormula, I do not think it requires complex state management.

Comment: Okay, and why do they need to be exported from seperate files? Are you planning on using `handleSaveFormula` and `editExpression` outside of the `Editor` component?

Comment: I am not litrally planning to use handleSaveFormula and editExpression outside of the Editor component, instead I am defining them in a different file in another directory and I am invoking them in the Editor component.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately you can't reference parts of a component outside of it's own scope. You could always pass `setMathEditorVisible` as an argument, but it might just be easier to define `handleSaveFormula` and `editExpression` inside of the `Editor` component. It keeps all logic regarding `Editor`'s state in one place and is pretty much the way how React was meant to be used.

Comment: I was trying redux toolkit the whole day now, but in vain, I created an infinite loop in the useEffect hook, I initialized mathEditorVisible as false and when I toggle its component, its state is just updated for the first time, and then an infinite loop occurs.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about if recoil is the convenient alternative in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just passed the state as an argument to the functions where I need to manage it and it works as expected, thank you guys for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because you can't import a local variable in a function.

However, fear not, this problem can be solved in a couple other ways:

### Parameters

You can pass `mathEditorVisible` and `setMathEditorVisible` into `Editor` and into your `handleSaveFormula` and `editExpression` functions from component of a higher level (e.g. page).

It will look something like this:

```
// page.tsx
const Page = () => {
  ...
  const [mathEditorVisible, setMathEditorVisible] = useState(false)
  ...
  return <>
   ...
   <Editor visible={mathEditorVisible} /> 
   ...
   <button onClick={() => {
     setMathEditorVisible(false)
     handleSaveFormula()
   }}>Your submit flow</button>
   <button onClick={() => {
     setMathEditorVisible(true)
     editExpression()
   }}>Your edit flow</button>
  </>
}
```

### Context

Another way to do this is put your variables into context (which would have to be on top of Editor component and the functions you're calling `setMathEditorVisible` in).

Context lets you access its values in any (even nested) child components.

So, in this situation you would store your `[mathEditorVisible, setMathEditorVisible]` in `value` property of a context component (`ContextObject.Provider`) created by `React.createContext`. Then later you can access the values through `useContext` hook, passing the original context object as the argument.

Here's the example:

```
// mathEditor.tsx
const EditorContext = React.createContext<[boolean, (v: boolean) => void]>([false, () => {}])

const Editor = () => {
  const [mathEditorVisible] = useContext(EditorContext)
  ...
}


// page.tsx

import { EditorContext } from './mathEditor.tsx' // Or any other path


const SubmitFlow = () => {
  ...
  const [,setMathEditorVisible] = useContext(EditorContext)
  return <>
    ...
    <button onClick={() => setMathEditorVisible(false)}>Submit</button>
  </>
}
const EditFlow = () => {
  ...
  const [,setMathEditorVisible] = useContext(EditorContext)
  return <>
    ...
    <button onClick={() => setMathEditorVisible(true)}>Edit</button>
  </>
}

const Page = () => {
  const [mathEditorVisible, setMathEditorVisible] = useState(false)
  return <>
    ...
    <EditorContext.Provider value={[mathEditorVisible, setMathEditorVisible]}>
      <Editor />
      <SubmitFlow />
      <EditFlow />
    </EditorContext.Provider>
  </>
}
```

Note that with context, since you have to call useContext hook, you would need to retrieve values in a component, and if needed, pass it to underlying functions.

### Conclusion

As some other people already mentioned, you're probably better off with the first approach. However, it's good to know how context works, in case you need to access something in a lot unconnected components/places.

Comment: I understand your concern, however this answer was not generated by ChatGPT, nor any other LLM. I just thought it would be nice to explain the topic in-depth.

And I don't even have an openai account.

Comment: I would honestly prove that it's not, but I'm not sure how

Comment: You're doing human things now. This helps. :)

Comment: I withdraw my concern.